# Deleting duplicate cells from notebook

Tags: list-manipulation, notebooks, cells

I need to delete all duplicate cells in my notebook, keeping just one occurrence of each pair (or tuple). No need to choose which to keep. 
Is there a (simple) way to do it?

Comment: Are they exact duplicates by the structure (Ctrl+Shit+E)? How did it happen?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If the cells are "duplicates" of eachother, why do you need to choose which one you keep? You could realize this by importing the notebook as "notebook expression" and do a simple expression replacement.

Comment: @halirutan The notebook has a lot of cells (10000+). Some (few hundreds) have one or two duplicate (just some of them). I cannot do the replacement by hand as they are too many. I need to preserve just one single copy of each. Is there a hack to do it programmatically? I mean, how could I scan the cells and keep track of duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the [Low-Level Notebook Programming](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LowLevelNotebookProgramming.html) guide.

Create a notebook with [`CreateDocument`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateDocument.html) for the example that has duplicate cells.

```
SeedRandom[123];
nb = CreateDocument[Table[ExpressionCell[n, "Input"], {n, RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 20]}]]
```

The [`Cells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cells.html) can be [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html)'ed their [`NotebookRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookRead.html) representation.  They will have different [`CellChangeTimes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellChangeTimes.html) so this is made to be the same for all cells.  The first of each gathered sublist is kept and the [`Rest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rest.html) are [`NotebookDelete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookDelete.html)'ed from the notebook.

```
NotebookDelete@
 Flatten[Rest /@ 
   GatherBy[Cells[nb], 
    NotebookRead[#] /. {HoldPattern[CellChangeTimes -> _] -> Nothing} &]
  ]
```

The duplicate cells are now deleted.  For the cases where there are no duplicates then they will form a sublist with a single cell.  This cell will be removed by `Rest` so that it is not deleted.

If running this in the notebook you want to clean-up then replace `Cells[nb]` with `Cells[]` to get the cells in the current notebook.

The cells have to be identical in their `NotebookRead` form for this to work.

Hope this helps.